# Rounded rectangle with stroke -- svg quality compared to div

Tags: svg

I understand that there is a different render process, but why is the stroke so funky on rounded rectangles compared to a rounded div with a border?

```css
body {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.svg-square {
  fill: #75604A;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.div-square {
  background-color: #75604A;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin:  20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span>svg</span>

<svg width="60" height="60">
  <rect class="svg-square" width="60" height="60" rx="10" />
</svg>

<div class="div-square"></div>
<span>div</span>
```

FIDDLE: https://codepen.io/kirkbross/pen/gEGGvx

It seems like it's a half pixel stroke on the svg and even when I increase it to 2, the sides seem thinner than the top and bottom.

I want to understand the physics here. This example is an svg with a stroke of 1. These corners seem janky compared to a div with a border.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `svg{overflow:visible;}`

Comment: That did the trick. I always assumed `visible` was the default for overflow. I also created a separate transparent square for the stroke and drew it after the filled square so it's on top.

Answer (score 2):

Well part of it is that you're cutting off half the stroke-width because your rect is exactly the size of your svg element. Look at:

```
 <rect x="1" y="1" class="svg-square" width="58" height="58" rx="10" />
```

Still not as good at rounded corners as CSS drawing - but much more reasonable.